# How to resolve error upgrading scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, conda

I receive errors when trying to upgrade sci-kit learn. Please see code below.
When checking the version of sci-kit in Python it tells me that `sklearn has no attribute __version`. However, when checking on conda list it shows that sci-kit learn 0.20.3 is installed. Not sure how to resolve the error below.

### Package Plan

```
(base) C:\Users\Marilyns.CORNASTONE>conda update scikit-learn
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done
environment location: C:\Users\Marilyns.CORNASTONE\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Anaconda3

  added / updated specs:
    - scikit-learn


The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  joblib             pkgs/main/win-64::joblib-0.13.2-py37_0
  json5              pkgs/main/noarch::json5-0.8.4-py_0
  mock               pkgs/main/win-64::mock-3.0.5-py37_0
  sphinxcontrib-app~ pkgs/main/noarch::sphinxcontrib-applehelp-1.0.1-py_0
  sphinxcontrib-dev~ pkgs/main/noarch::sphinxcontrib-devhelp-1.0.1-py_0
  sphinxcontrib-htm~ pkgs/main/noarch::sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp-1.0.2-py_0
  sphinxcontrib-jsm~ pkgs/main/noarch::sphinxcontrib-jsmath-1.0.1-py_0
  sphinxcontrib-qth~ pkgs/main/noarch::sphinxcontrib-qthelp-1.0.2-py_0
  sphinxcontrib-ser~ pkgs/main/noarch::sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml-1.1.3-py_0

The following packages will be UPDATED:

  anaconda-project   pkgs/main/win-64::anaconda-project-0.~ --> pkgs/main/noarch
::anaconda-project-0.8.3-py_0
  astropy                              3.1.2-py37he774522_0 --> 3.2.1-py37he7745
22_0
  babel                pkgs/main/win-64::babel-2.6.0-py37_0 --> pkgs/main/noarch
::babel-2.7.0-py_0
  backports          pkgs/main/win-64::backports-1.0-py37_1 --> pkgs/main/noarch
::backports-1.0-py_2
  bitarray                             0.8.3-py37hfa6e2cd_0 --> 0.9.3-py37he7745
22_0
  blosc                                   1.15.0-h7bd577a_0 --> 1.16.3-h7bd577a_
0
  bokeh                                        1.0.4-py37_0 --> 1.2.0-py37_0
  bzip2                                    1.0.6-hfa6e2cd_5 --> 1.0.8-he774522_0

  cffi                                1.12.2-py37h7a1dbc1_1 --> 1.12.3-py37h7a1d
bc1_0
  cloudpickle        pkgs/main/win-64::cloudpickle-0.8.0-p~ --> pkgs/main/noarch
::cloudpickle-1.2.1-py_0
  cryptography                         2.6.1-py37h7a1dbc1_0 --> 2.7-py37h7a1dbc1
_0
  curl                                    7.64.0-h2a8f88b_2 --> 7.64.1-h2a8f88b_
0
  cython                              0.29.6-py37ha925a31_0 --> 0.29.12-py37ha92
5a31_0
  cytoolz                            0.9.0.1-py37hfa6e2cd_1 --> 0.10.0-py37he774
522_0
  dask                  pkgs/main/win-64::dask-1.1.4-py37_1 --> pkgs/main/noarch
::dask-2.1.0-py_0
  dask-core          pkgs/main/win-64::dask-core-1.1.4-py3~ --> pkgs/main/noarch
::dask-core-2.1.0-py_0
  defusedxml         pkgs/main/win-64::defusedxml-0.5.0-py~ --> pkgs/main/noarch
::defusedxml-0.6.0-py_0
  distributed        pkgs/main/win-64::distributed-1.26.0-~ --> pkgs/main/noarch
::distributed-2.1.0-py_0
  fastcache                            1.0.2-py37hfa6e2cd_2 --> 1.1.0-py37he7745
22_0
  filelock           pkgs/main/win-64::filelock-3.0.10-py3~ --> pkgs/main/noarch
::filelock-3.0.12-py_0
  flask                pkgs/main/win-64::flask-1.0.2-py37_1 --> pkgs/main/noarch
::flask-1.1.1-py_0
  glob2                  pkgs/main/win-64::glob2-0.6-py37_1 --> pkgs/main/noarch
::glob2-0.7-py_0
  importlib_metadata                             0.8-py37_0 --> 0.17-py37_1
  intel-openmp                                   2019.3-203 --> 2019.4-245
  ipykernel                            5.1.0-py37h39e3cac_0 --> 5.1.1-py37h39e3c
ac_0
  ipython                              7.4.0-py37h39e3cac_0 --> 7.6.1-py37h39e3c
ac_0
  ipywidgets         pkgs/main/win-64::ipywidgets-7.4.2-py~ --> pkgs/main/noarch
::ipywidgets-7.5.0-py_0
  isort                                       4.3.16-py37_0 --> 4.3.21-py37_0
  jdcal                  pkgs/main/win-64::jdcal-1.4-py37_0 --> pkgs/main/noarch
::jdcal-1.4.1-py_0
  jinja2                                        2.10-py37_0 --> 2.10.1-py37_0
  jupyter_client     pkgs/main/win-64::jupyter_client-5.2.~ --> pkgs/main/noarch
::jupyter_client-5.3.1-py_0
  jupyter_core       pkgs/main/win-64::jupyter_core-4.4.0-~ --> pkgs/main/noarch
::jupyter_core-4.5.0-py_0
  jupyterlab                          0.35.4-py37hf63ae98_0 --> 1.0.2-py37hf63ae
98_0
  jupyterlab_server  pkgs/main/win-64::jupyterlab_server-0~ --> pkgs/main/noarch
::jupyterlab_server-1.0.0-py_0
  kiwisolver                           1.0.1-py37h6538335_0 --> 1.1.0-py37ha925a
31_0
  lazy-object-proxy                    1.3.1-py37hfa6e2cd_2 --> 1.4.1-py37he7745
22_0
  libcurl                                 7.64.0-h2a8f88b_2 --> 7.64.1-h2a8f88b_
0
  libpng                                  1.6.36-h2a8f88b_0 --> 1.6.37-h2a8f88b_
0
  libssh2                                  1.8.0-h7a1dbc1_4 --> 1.8.2-h7a1dbc1_0

  llvmlite                            0.28.0-py37ha925a31_0 --> 0.29.0-py37ha925
a31_0
  lxml                                 4.3.2-py37h1350720_0 --> 4.3.4-py37h13507
20_0
  matplotlib                           3.0.3-py37hc8f65d3_0 --> 3.1.0-py37hc8f65
d3_0
  mkl                                            2019.3-203 --> 2019.4-245
  mkl_fft                             1.0.10-py37h14836fe_0 --> 1.0.12-py37h1483
6fe_0
  more-itertools                               6.0.0-py37_0 --> 7.0.0-py37_0
  nbconvert          pkgs/main/win-64::nbconvert-5.4.1-py3~ --> pkgs/main/noarch
::nbconvert-5.5.0-py_0
  networkx            pkgs/main/win-64::networkx-2.2-py37_1 --> pkgs/main/noarch
::networkx-2.3-py_0
  nltk                                           3.4-py37_1 --> 3.4.4-py37_0
  numba                               0.43.1-py37hf9181ef_0 --> 0.44.1-py37hf918
1ef_0
  numpy                               1.16.2-py37h19fb1c0_0 --> 1.16.4-py37h19fb
1c0_0
  numpy-base                          1.16.2-py37hc3f5095_0 --> 1.16.4-py37hc3f5
095_0
  numpydoc           pkgs/main/win-64::numpydoc-0.8.0-py37~ --> pkgs/main/noarch
::numpydoc-0.9.1-py_0
  openpyxl           pkgs/main/win-64::openpyxl-2.6.1-py37~ --> pkgs/main/noarch
::openpyxl-2.6.2-py_0
  parso                pkgs/main/win-64::parso-0.3.4-py37_0 --> pkgs/main/noarch
::parso-0.5.0-py_0
  partd               pkgs/main/win-64::partd-0.3.10-py37_1 --> pkgs/main/noarch
::partd-1.0.0-py_0
  path.py            pkgs/main/win-64::path.py-11.5.0-py37~ --> pkgs/main/noarch
::path.py-12.0.1-py_0
  pathlib2                                     2.3.3-py37_0 --> 2.3.4-py37_0
  pillow                               5.4.1-py37hdc69c19_0 --> 6.1.0-py37hdc69c
19_0
  pip                                         19.0.3-py37_0 --> 19.1.1-py37_0
  pluggy              pkgs/main/win-64::pluggy-0.9.0-py37_0 --> pkgs/main/noarch
::pluggy-0.12.0-py_0
  prometheus_client  pkgs/main/win-64::prometheus_client-0~ --> pkgs/main/noarch
::prometheus_client-0.7.1-py_0
  psutil                               5.6.1-py37he774522_0 --> 5.6.3-py37he7745
22_0
  pycurl                            7.43.0.2-py37h7a1dbc1_0 --> 7.43.0.3-py37h7a
1dbc1_0
  pygments           pkgs/main/win-64::pygments-2.3.1-py37~ --> pkgs/main/noarch
::pygments-2.4.2-py_0
  pyparsing          pkgs/main/win-64::pyparsing-2.3.1-py3~ --> pkgs/main/noarch
::pyparsing-2.4.0-py_0
  pysocks                                      1.6.8-py37_0 --> 1.7.0-py37_0
  pytables                             3.5.1-py37h1da0976_0 --> 3.5.2-py37h1da09
76_1
  pytest                                       4.3.1-py37_0 --> 5.0.1-py37_0
  python-libarchive~                             2.8-py37_6 --> 2.8-py37_10
  pytz                 pkgs/main/win-64::pytz-2018.9-py37_0 --> pkgs/main/noarch
::pytz-2019.1-py_0
  pywavelets                           1.0.2-py37h8c2d366_0 --> 1.0.3-py37h8c2d3
66_1
  pyyaml                                 5.1-py37he774522_0 --> 5.1.1-py37he7745
22_0
  qtconsole          pkgs/main/win-64::qtconsole-4.4.3-py3~ --> pkgs/main/noarch
::qtconsole-4.5.1-py_0
  qtpy                  pkgs/main/win-64::qtpy-1.7.0-py37_1 --> pkgs/main/noarch
::qtpy-1.8.0-py_0
  requests                                    2.21.0-py37_0 --> 2.22.0-py37_0
  rope                 pkgs/main/win-64::rope-0.12.0-py37_0 --> pkgs/main/noarch
::rope-0.14.0-py_0
  scikit-image                        0.14.2-py37ha925a31_0 --> 0.15.0-py37ha925
a31_0
  scikit-learn                        0.20.3-py37h343c172_0 --> 0.21.2-py37h6288
b17_0
  setuptools                                  40.8.0-py37_0 --> 41.0.1-py37_0
  snowballstemmer    pkgs/main/win-64::snowballstemmer-1.2~ --> pkgs/main/noarch
::snowballstemmer-1.9.0-py_0
  sphinx              pkgs/main/win-64::sphinx-1.8.5-py37_0 --> pkgs/main/noarch
::sphinx-2.1.2-py_0
  sphinxcontrib-web~ pkgs/main/win-64::sphinxcontrib-websu~ --> pkgs/main/noarch
::sphinxcontrib-websupport-1.1.2-py_0
  spyder                                       3.3.3-py37_0 --> 3.3.6-py37_0
  spyder-kernels                               0.4.2-py37_0 --> 0.5.1-py37_0
  sqlalchemy                           1.3.1-py37he774522_0 --> 1.3.5-py37he7745
22_0
  sqlite                                  3.27.2-he774522_0 --> 3.29.0-he774522_
0
  statsmodels                          0.9.0-py37h452e1ab_0 --> 0.10.0-py37h8c2d
366_0
  sympy                                          1.3-py37_0 --> 1.4-py37_0
  tblib                pkgs/main/win-64::tblib-1.3.2-py37_0 --> pkgs/main/noarch
::tblib-1.4.0-py_0
  terminado                                    0.8.1-py37_1 --> 0.8.2-py37_0
  toolz                pkgs/main/win-64::toolz-0.9.0-py37_0 --> pkgs/main/noarch
::toolz-0.10.0-py_0
  tornado                              6.0.2-py37he774522_0 --> 6.0.3-py37he7745
22_0
  tqdm                 pkgs/main/win-64::tqdm-4.31.1-py37_1 --> pkgs/main/noarch
::tqdm-4.32.1-py_0
  urllib3                                     1.24.1-py37_0 --> 1.24.2-py37_0
  vs2015_runtime                     14.15.26706-h3a45250_0 --> 14.15.26706-h3a4
5250_4
  werkzeug           pkgs/main/win-64::werkzeug-0.14.1-py3~ --> pkgs/main/noarch
::werkzeug-0.15.4-py_0
  wheel                                       0.33.1-py37_0 --> 0.33.4-py37_0
  widgetsnbextension                           3.4.2-py37_0 --> 3.5.0-py37_0
  wrapt                               1.11.1-py37he774522_0 --> 1.11.2-py37he774
522_0
  xlsxwriter         pkgs/main/win-64::xlsxwriter-1.1.5-py~ --> pkgs/main/noarch
::xlsxwriter-1.1.8-py_0
  xlwings                                     0.15.4-py37_0 --> 0.15.8-py37_0
  zict                  pkgs/main/win-64::zict-0.1.4-py37_0 --> pkgs/main/noarch
::zict-1.0.0-py_0
  zipp                  pkgs/main/win-64::zipp-0.3.3-py37_1 --> pkgs/main/noarch
::zipp-0.5.1-py_0


Proceed ([y]/n)? y

**

    Preparing transaction: done
    Verifying transaction: failed
    ClobberError: This transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared path.
      packages: defaults::spyder-3.3.6-py37_0, defaults::spyder-3.3.6-py37_0
      path: 'menu/spyder_shortcut.json'
    CondaVerificationError: The package for scikit-learn located at C:\Users\Marilyn
    s.CORNASTONE\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Anaconda3\pkgs\scikit-learn-0.21.
    2-py37h6288b17_0
    appears to be corrupted. The path 'Lib/site-packages/sklearn/datasets/tests/data
    /openml/292/api-v1-json-data-list-data_name-australian-limit-2-data_version-1-st
    atus-deactivated.json.gz'
    specified in the package manifest cannot be found.
    CondaVerificationError: The package for scikit-learn located at C:\Users\Marilyn
    s.CORNASTONE\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Anaconda3\pkgs\scikit-learn-0.21.
    2-py37h6288b17_0
    appears to be corrupted. The path 'Lib/site-packages/sklearn/datasets/tests/data
    /openml/40675/api-v1-json-data-list-data_name-glass2-limit-2-data_version-1-stat
    us-deactivated.json.gz'
    specified in the package manifest cannot be found.
```

Any leads will be really helpful.

Comment: you can use pip command also to install the package and if you will face the same error then use the wheel file to install scikit learn  https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#   and also you can use the command given in https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/scikit-learn  to install the scikit-learn

Comment: pleaase notice that to get the version you should give `import sklearn` and `sklearn.__version__`